# flat file datetime issue

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-expressions

I have a flat file with this  datetime format `5/24/2017 05:12:44.243 PM`. I have been struggling to convert this format to something like this `2017-05-24 17:12:44.243`. I tried using this derived column expression

```
 (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(EventDate,FINDSTRING(EventDate,"/",2) + 1,4) + 
   "-" + SUBSTRING(EventDate,1,FINDSTRING(EventDate,"/",1) - 1) + 
   "-" + SUBSTRING(EventDate,FINDSTRING(EventDate,"/",1) + 
           1,FINDSTRING(EventDate,"/",2) - FINDSTRING(EventDate,"/",1) - 1) +
   " " + SUBSTRING(EventDate,FINDSTRING(EventDate," ",1) + 1,8))
```

where "EventDate" is the column name

but I am getting the result in this format "2017-05-22 05:21:00.000" also this is not converting the 12 hour to 24 hour. I am new to SSIS development and been struggling on this really long. Please help me on this, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Check [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) and [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). You may just *not* need to do any conversion, just let SQL Server know which is your original format, and let it import your flat files.

Comment: Is this field a datetime or a string?

Comment: I already tried with out using any conversion but ended up getting in error in SSIS tranformation.

Comment: this is a datetime  field.

Comment: Maybe this helps, https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1803581/date-format-YYYMMDD-HHMMSS-ssis-expression

Comment: link shown is helpful but I need milliseconds too and hours should be displayed in 24 hour format

Comment: The link McNets provided was to get a date string into an SSIS variable; You'd be doing something a little different, converting a string value to a date, and inserting that into your column. You'll want to look up how to use the Script Component in your dataflow. The command that should parse your date format is `DateTime.ParseExact(<myDateCol>, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, replacing `<myDateCol> with the reference for your actual date column. This assumes that the date format not only uses a single digit for months from 1-9, but does the same for days.